# What would the output impedance be if R5 And R6 were not in the circuit?

Tags: impedance, output

[image]

If R5 = R6 = 10 ohms then I think that the output impedance would be 10 ohms.

What would it be if R5 and R6 were not in the circuit?

Thanks

Comment: Infinity if you ignored RL.

Answer (score 2):

Without the emitter resistors, the output impedance (and other characteristics of the circuit) would depend very strongly on the specific characteristics of the transistors, which can vary widely even among transistors from the same "batch". The resistors are used specifically to reduce or eliminate that dependency.

Instead, there are other ways to reduce output impedance, such as increasing the open-loop gain of the circuit and then applying negative feedback directly from the output terminal.

Answer (score 1):

Emitter resistors R5 and R6 are present to prevent Q2 & Q3 going into thermal runaway. I would not replace them with jumper links.

If R5 = 0 Ohms the impedance looking into the high-side driver is \$1/g_m + R_3/\beta\$.

As Dave T. suggests negative feedback is a superior approach to reducing the effective output impedance of the amplifier.

Comment: I am trying to setup a design procedure for computing the various component values for this amplifier circuit. The only part that I can't get my head around, is arriving at the values for R5 and R6. The circuit that I breadboarded employs 10 ohm resistors and thermal runaway is a problem with smaller values, but there must be away to compute the values.

Comment: To prevent thermal runaway you want your Diodes to thermally track Q1 and Q2 or the rise is power dissipation per degC to be less that the thermal conductance of your heat sink in W/degC